# MATLAB: Retrieving GUI data from a loop

Tags: matlab, user-interface

What's the best practice in the following scenario:

I have loop that starts upon button press and during execution the iterations should respond to inputs through the GUI (e.g. slider value change). This is not possible in an uninterruptible loop so therefore, a working but clumsy solution is to use a pause such that:

```
while true
    get(handles.slider1,'value')
    pause(0.5)
end
```

Are there alternative, more elegant solutions to this problem?

Edit: as clarification, a variant that does NOT work (i.e. does not output changing slider values):

```
while true
        get(handles.slider1,'value')     
end
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to use a separate event loop rather than utilizing GUI callbacks to perform actions when changes are made to the controls?

Comment: I need the loop to process a continuous stream of data and as long as I am in the loop, GUI callbacks will not be processed (unless I include the pause). Maybe there is a loop-less solution for my problem that I am not aware of. Is that what you're pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the slider value to a global variable.

```
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global SliderValue;
SliderValue = hObject.Value;
```

Then access `SliderValue` from any function.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global SliderValue;
while a<100
    a = SliderValue + a;
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how your answer addresses my question. As long as I am in an uninterruptible loop, the slider1_Callback function will not be processed and therefore, I will only have access to the old SliderValue.

Comment: @JohnSmith It will be processed. The Gui seems to be run at a seperate thread, so when you in the loop, Gui can still respond you. However, you can't use guidata, because when in the loop, although guidata can be updated in other function, the loop will keep using the old data.

Comment: Yes, you're technically correct. However, as you said, guidata will only retrieve only the old data which is the core of the problem.

Comment: @JohnSmith That is why I suggest using a [global variable](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html), which is not bound to appdata, but shared among different functions, gui and scripts.

Comment: Ah, now I understand! I'll try your solution.

Comment: @JohnSmith What's the current state of the problem? Have you managed to solve it?